# How to detect redraw of screen has completed after soft keyboard closes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

In my Android application, I have an activity containing nested fragments, with the activity having the property of:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

One of the nested fragments contains a button, which when pressed, opens a dialog fragment directly above where the button is located.

When this button is pressed whilst the soft keyboard is open, the soft keyboard will automatically close.  **However, the issue I am having is that the dialog fragment will be drawn based on the position of the button before the soft keyboard closes, instead of after the soft keyboard has closed and the redraw of the screen has completed.**

What I have done so far is:

- On the onClick event, check if the soft keyboard is open - if it is, don't open the dialog fragment immediately (instead, set a flag)
- The fragment implements View.OnLayoutChangeListener - when onLayoutChange() is called, it checks the flag to see if the dialog fragment needs to be opened (if so, it then gets the coordinates of the button at this time, and opens the dialog fragment)

What I am finding is that when onLayoutChange() is called, the screen hasn't completely redrawn - the soft keyboard has closed, but the button hasn't moved towards the bottom of the screen (ie. there is blank space where the keyboard was).

Therefore, I need to know when the screen has finished redrawing so that I can ensure the button is in its correct position before the dialog fragment is opened.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I now have a solution to this...

1. Use the View.OnLayoutChangeListener.
2. Within the onLayoutChange() function, I create a local broadcast to open the dialog fragment, which passes through the view in the broadcast.
3. Only once in the BroadcastManager onReceive() function should the coordinates of the button be obtained before creating the DialogFragment.

As far as I understand, this works because the onReceive() function is called in the UI thread, which means that it will be executed in the same thread, but most importantly after, the screen has been redrawn.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement View.OnLayoutChangeListener for your ButtonView instead of Fragment

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this still doesn't work for me - when onLayoutChange() is called within my Button class, it hasn't been redrawn yet.